# Launch a development local server with live reload feature for static and dynamic pages in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, visual-studio-code

Many times i have asked related this quations but no one is answered properly.My Qa is how to Launch a development local server with live reload feature for static and dynamic pages in VS code using following the josn files not plugins?

//this is sample json files//

//Folder//
//folder path like this http://localhost/myfiles/Myproject

```
Myproject
  index.html
  linkpages
      ->demo1.html
      ->demo2.html
  app.js
  app.ts
```

launch.json

```
{ 
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${file}"
    }
]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "msbuild",
        "args": [
            // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.
            "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
            "/t:build"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "presentation": {
            // Reveal the output only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "reveal": "silent"
        },
        // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
]
  }
```